# Why pick Flush over Rapid Fire?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

[Assault soldiers](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Assault_Class) reaching the rank of Lieutenant can choose between [Flush](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Flush) or [Rapid Fire](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Rapid_Fire).  I chose Flush for my first Assault soldier and used it probably twice; my second Assault class took Rapid Fire and uses it almost constantly.

In what scenario would one ever choose an Assault build that made extensive (or even reasonable) use of the Flush skill?

Comment: I'm hoping Enemy Within will update this ability during their rebalance. It's pretty poor at the moment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per StrixVaria, the one good use for **Flush** is that it triggers Overwatch attacks when it forces the enemy to move.  As an enemy in full cover has 40% defence (which is a -40% to aim), putting your other troopers in Overwatch and forcing the enemy to move via Flush may be better than taking direct shots at the enemy.

Ultimately, Flush is the one Assault ability that I never use, for two reasons.

1. It is unreliable.  It doesn't truly force the enemy out of cover - it forces them to make a move.  They can (and will) move to another covered position - sometimes moving from half-cover to full cover and sometimes moving in such a way that they make your position worse.  Using explosives to deal with cover is far more reliable.
2. **Rapid Fire** is awesome when you need something with a lot of hit points dead, or [when you need to guarantee a hit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89377/when-is-rapid-fire-better-than-regular-fire).

Comment: Would an enemy moving due to flush trigger overwatch attacks? That's the only thing I can think of that might make it a little bit useful.

Comment: @StrixVaria - Yes it does, so it could be used with Overwatching Opportunistic Snipers (as an example) to force a kill against something in full cover.

Comment: @StrixVaria That's a brilliant idea; I'd rather take the -15 Aim penalty from overwatch than try to hit an alien with full or even half cover.  I'm going to give that a try and verify that it works.    The problem I expect to have is that the alien's movement is random, so it could move in such a way as to avoid my overwatch.

Comment: @JasonBerkan Your comment is more appropriate than your actual answer.  If you edit your answer to include why you _would_ use Flush instead of why you wouldn't, I can accept it as correct.  :)

Comment: Flush is also useful to finish off damaged enemies, because it almost always hits with its +30% Aim bonus, even through high cover. If half damage is enough to kill the target, problem solved! My one Assault with Flush saw a lot of use with it on the final mission against the early enemies.

Comment: @PaulZ - Also true, though at the end game, Mind Fray is far more reliable whenever a non-robotic enemy is down to 5 or less HP.

Comment: I honestly doubt the flush overwatch gambit is worth the effort, you may as well rapid fire the covered enemy and have a good chance to kill it or destroy its cover.

Comment: Flush also has +30 hit and -50% damage.  Ideal when you need to do one more point of damage.